# Getting sum of field in mysql selecting max values in case of duplicate field

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct, max

I have this

```
------------------------------------
 course_id  | total marks | year  
------------------------------------
   1              50         1   -------> I want to remove this from the sum               
   2              50         1
   3              50         1  
   1              100        2  
------------------------------------
```

I really have no Idea how to do this ,

I have 3 distinct courses ,
and  I want to get sum of total marks but with a distinct course_id considering the max number of year , the result should be  200  ,  thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a subquery to determine the maximum year for each course, then join that with the table again to obtain the marks:

```
SELECT SUM(`total marks`)
FROM   `table`
  NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT course_id, MAX(year) AS year
    FROM   `table`
    GROUP BY course_id
  ) AS y
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99cef/1).

Answer (score 2):

As simple as this:

```
SELECT SUM(m) FROM (
                    SELECT   total_marks AS m
                    FROM     table AS t
                    WHERE    year = (
                                     SELECT MAX(year) 
                                     FROM   table
                                     WHERE  course_id = t.course_id
                                    )
                   ) AS v
```